# Dictionary<>.ContainsKey gives RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

In .cshtml i want to check if a key exist in a `Directory<int, Object>` but i get always an error and can't find why.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> weekAndYear in @ViewBag.WeekAndYears)
{
    int key = int.Parse(weekAndYear.Value + "" + weekAndYear.Key);

    bool exist = ViewBag.Menus.ContainsKey(key);
}
```

The error I get:

```
The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,Object>.this[int] has some invalid arguments
```

When I use only the .Key or .Value it still works.

**Edit - Solution**

What the problem is, I don't know, but I have solved the problem with the following code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> weekAndYear in @ViewBag.WeekAndYears)
    {
        int key = int.Parse(weekAndYear.Value + "" + weekAndYear.Key);

        bool exist = ((Dictionary<int, Object>)ViewBag.Menus).ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Comment: where do you get this error and what is the `@ViewBag.WeekAndYears` ?

Comment: In your @foreach loop your **KeyValuePair** should be of KeyValuePair<int, object> rather than KeyValuePair<int, int>. This might be the problem.

Comment: `@ViewBag.WeekAndYears` is `Dictionary<int, int>`. I get the error on the `ContainsKey(key)`. `@ViewBag.Menus` is `Dictionary<int, Object>`

Comment: what is the value of key when the lookup fails?

Comment: @InContext the value of `key` is an `int` even if it fails. `@ViewBag.WeekAndYears` contains `{31: 2014, 32: 2014, 33: 2014}`

Comment: ok and how do you set ViewBad.Menus? See @Alek Depler comment below re dynamic types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the problem is, I don't know, but I have solved the problem with the following code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> weekAndYear in @ViewBag.WeekAndYears)
    {
        int key = int.Parse(weekAndYear.Value + "" + weekAndYear.Key);

        bool exist = ((Dictionary<int, Object>)ViewBag.Menus).ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps try using TryGetValue instead of ContainsKey and see if it works:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> weekAndYear in @ViewBag.WeekAndYears)
{
    int key = int.Parse(weekAndYear.Value + "" + weekAndYear.Key); 
    Object outValue;
    bool exist = Menus.TryGetValue(key, out outValue);
}
```

Comment: Nice, that works also! I have used another solution and placed it in the question area, because I can't answer my own question.